# PHP Check for steam valid link

Tags: php

I want to change this to a code that will check if the steam trade link is valid or not.

Worst case scenario - To check if the steam trade link exists at all.

Best case scenario - If the link belongs to the logged in user.

```
var link = $('input[rel="get-trade-link"]').val();
if (link.indexOf('https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=') < 0) {
        var txt;
    if(getLang() == "ru") txt = '<div><div><strong>Error!</strong><br>Enter valid link</div></div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am too late (very late), but for other people randomly scrolling:

You can check that tradelink belongs to user by comparing user's steamid3 with `partner` paramteter. This parameter IS steamid3 of user.
If you want check if tradelink exists just call request to this link and check if not 404